# default linker script for debugging information

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, default, ld

I am trying to use gdb for learning debugging. When I compile the following code using no options, gdb points out that no debugging symbols were found.

```
int main()
 {
  return 0;
 }

$gcc debug.c
$gdb a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) quit
```

But when I give the `-g` flag with `gcc`, following output is seen:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) Quit
(gdb) quit
```

How do I figure out what is wrong and see if the linker has enabled stripping of the debugging information somewhere?

Comment: we'd need the full build traces (compiler+linker) and/or the command line / makefile used.

Comment: i dont use any makefile explicitly

Answer (score 0):

There's no stripping involved here, since there's no debug inclusion in the first place.

`-g` option is *required* to enable debug information.

By default (without any option), debug information is *not* embedded in the object files

So the correct way is: enable `-g` to tell the compiler to embed debug symbols, else they're not included and `gdb` does not find them.

(yes, another way to avoid the debugger to find them is to pass `-Wl,--strip-debug` to the linker, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

> But when I give the `-g` flag with `gcc`, following output is seen:
>
> `Reading symbols from a.out...done.`

That's the output you get when `gdb` reads the debug symbols without errors. It succeeded so at that point the debugger is ready for you to tell it where to put breakpoints and to run the program being debugged.